# Ansible: Pip install directly from s3 using s3 module

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible, ansible-playbook, pip

How do I Pip install directly from s3 using s3 module in Ansible?

with git I would:

```
- name: Install module from git repo
  pip: name=\"git+git@bitbucket.org:MYORG/REPONAME.git\" executable=/usr/local/bin/pip2.7
  sudo: yes
```

Can I do the same with s3 ?

Ideally it would look like:

```
- name: Install module from s3
  pip: name=\"s3+s3://https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/latest.zip\" executable=/usr/local/bin/pip2.7
  sudo: yes
```

Comment: pip doesn't support s3 interaction.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is not a standard protocol so you can't use s3:// else where.

The ZIP file on S3 should have a public accessible URL given you have granted it [public-read](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) access.

So the following should work:

```
pip: name=https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/latest.zip
```